# How to get min and max with filter efficiently?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have DB like this (it's actually a much bigger than this):

```
 value
-------
 10
 20
 50
 600
 70
 800
```

I want to get min and max values, which satisfies some conditions (`where`).

I wrote these `selects`:

```sql
select value
from records 
where value >= 50
order by value asc 
limit 1
```

```sql
select value
from records 
where value <= 600
order by value desc
limit 1
```

But can I do it more efficiently and in one `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both conditions using `and` in `WHERE` clause and use `min()` and `max()` functions on `value`.

```
select max(value) as Maximum, min(value) as Minimum
from records  
where value >= 50
and value <= 600
```

Comment: Is it all calculated in one pass of table?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach uses conditional aggregation:

```
select max(value) filter (where value >= 50),
       min(value) filter (where value <= 600)
from records  ;
```

Filtering in the `WHERE` clause happens to work for the limits in your problem.  However, it does not generalize to more than two values.  And is cumbersome even for other pairs.

Comment: @MalyutinEgor . . . It generalizes more easily to multiple limits and aggregations.  For performance, you would have to check on your data.  I wouldn't expect it to be faster.